# Why did Dolan 36th mention about a parade of stewardesses marching?

Tags: the-last-witch-hunter

In Action Fantasy movie, *The Last Witch Hunter (2015)*, Kaulder says to Dolan 36th, who is about to retire as his handler:

> Dolan 36th: Find someone to trust.
>
> Kaulder: I trust you.
>
> Dolan 36th: Perhaps someone a little more comely. I know, I haven't
>   lived as long and rich a life as you, but I do know that there is more
>   to it than a **parade of stewardesses marching** to the dulcet tones of
>   Moonlight Sonata.

Comment: Didn't his latest hookup, the stewardess from the flight, literally just leave?